# Can I tell my model is overfittng?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, overfitting, dropout

I am developing fully convolutional model for semantic segmentation task and I tried to use spatial dropout layers to prevent overfitting of my model.

My model has interesting learning curves and I am not sure if it is overfitting or not. According to loss function my model is overfitting because it has smaller train loss than validation loss. But according to graph of mean intersection over union (mIoU) or other metrics my model is not overfitting because train metric curves (dashed) are uniformly under the validation metric curves (solid).
How can I now tell if my model is overfitting or not?

Here is graph. In left image is loss function and in right one are metrics (jaccard is mIoU, dice is F1 score):
[image]

Comment: It's probably overfitting.

Comment: You'll pretty much always have a higher out-of-sample loss than in-sample. That should not concern you.

Comment: Ok so when someone is telling about overfitting, it's only according to loss function?

Comment: I would expect that loss is somehow correlated to metrics

Comment: I would say that even if your metrics are not getting worse (such as in your case, right plot), but the loss is getting worse (val loss, left plot), then there is probably overfitting going on. It might not have much of an effect on your val data at this moment, but the effect might show when you test it on another set.

Comment: @user2974951 Ok then and how should I choose best model ? According to minimum in let's say epoch 100 in loss or maximum in epoch 250 according to jaccard index (mIoU) ?

Comment: Do you have another set of data for testing?

Comment: Yes, I have test set.

Comment: Then I would test these models on the test set, for ex. the model after 100 epochs and the one after 250 epochs, and choose the one that performs best on the test set. This should give you a better estimate of how well your model performs.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Thanks for help !